# UI-grid set column order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to set the initial column order for ui-grid from data that I am getting from an $http call. When configuring gridOptions.colDefs it does not appear that any properties exist for me to set with initial order. How do I go about setting the initial column order for the grid?

I also noticed that there is a gridColumn class within the ui.grid module which allows for the order to be set. If this is the case I am unclear how to set this class in the grid and the documentation is not very clear and lacks examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column order can be set simply by the order in which the columns appear in the columnDefs array. If you are getting your columns from an $http call just setup the columnDefs array based on that and it should work.